# Read original image using ALAssetsLibrary ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

My question might be weird. I am trying to get original from camera .It works in most of the photos.My testing device is iphone5. Normal size of an image from camera is 3264 and 2448 in width and heigh. But when I try to get photo from camera that are taken using Filters(Mono, Tonal, Noir, Fade, Chrome, Process, Transfer, or Instant)feature of iphone ,I get smaller size of image.Here is my code .Thank you.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary assetForURL:[appRecord valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
     {
         ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

         CGSize dimension = [rep dimensions];
         NSLog(@"%lld",[rep size])  ;
         NSLog(@"dimension %f and %f",dimension.width ,dimension.height);

         unsigned long imageSize = (unsigned long)[rep size];
         NSLog(@"%lu ",imageSize);

         uint8_t* imageBytes = malloc(imageSize);
         [rep getBytes:imageBytes fromOffset:0 length:imageSize error:nil];
         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:imageBytes length:imageSize freeWhenDone:YES];
         UIImage *myImg =[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: @TonyMkenu , I get IMG_0209.JPG .Format like "IMG_Number.JPG.

Comment: Finally I found that it is a bug of assets library. devforums.apple.com/message/1062519#1062519